# How to help tqdm figure out the total in a custom iterator

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm implementing my own iterator.  tqdm does not show a progressbar, as it does not know the total amount of elements in the list.  I don't want to use "total=" as it looks ugly.  Rather I would prefer to add something to my iterator that tqdm can use to figure out the total.

```
class Batches:
    def __init__(self, batches, target_input):
        self.batches = batches
        self.pos = 0
        self.target_input = target_input

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.pos < len(self.batches):
            minibatch = self.batches[self.pos]
            target = minibatch[:, :, self.target_input]
            self.pos += 1
            return minibatch, target
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def __len__(self):
        return self.batches.len()
```

Is this even possible?  What to add to the above code...

Using tqdm like below..

```
for minibatch, target in tqdm(Batches(test, target_input)):

    output = lstm(minibatch)
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    writer.add_scalar('loss', loss, tensorboard_step)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The original question states:

> I don't want to use "total=" as it looks ugly. Rather I would prefer to add something to my iterator that tqdm can use to figure out the total.

However, the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51083782/655404) explicitly states to use `total`:

> ```py
> with tqdm(total=len(my_iterable)) as progress_bar:
> ```

In fact, the given example is more complicated than it would need to be as the original question did not ask for complex updating of the bar. Hence,

```py
for i in tqdm(my_iterable, total=my_total):
    do_something()
```

is actually sufficient already (as the author, @emem, already noted in a comment).

---

This question is relatively old (4 years at the time of writing this), yet looking at tqdm's code, one can see that [already from the very beginning](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/blame/39e814b2d692479b677aef46618d2881fb8cb791/tqdm/_tqdm.py#L158) (8 years ago at the time of writing this) the behavior was to default to `total = len(iterable)` in case `total` is not given.

Thus, the **correct answer to the question** is to implement `__len__`. Which, as is stated in the question, the original example already implements. Hence, it should already work correctly.

A full toy example to test the behavior can be found in the following (please note the comment above the `__len__` method):

```py
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm


class Iter:

    def __init__(self, n=10):
        self.n = n
        self.iter = iter(range(n))

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.iter)

    # commenting the next two lines disables showing the bar
    # due to tqdm not knowing the total number of elements:
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n


it = Iter()
for i in tqdm(it):
    sleep(0.2)
```

---

Looking at what tqdm does exactly:

```py
try:
    total = len(iterable)
except (TypeError, AttributeError):
    total = None
```

... and since we do not know exactly what @Duane used as `batches`, I would think that this is basically just a well hidden typo (`self.batches.len()`), which causes an `AttributeError` that is caught within tqdm.

If `batches` is just a sequence type, then this was probably the intended definition:

```py
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.batches)
```

The definition of `__next__` (using `len(self.batches)`) also points in this direction.

Comment: Good catch! I originally answered this question after searching for a way to solve two issues: first I was using a generator (so using `len()` was not relevant and total was `None` as you mentioned), and second I iterated over batches and wanted to update the total amount of items processed (that is, update the progress bar with the number of items inside the currently processed batch, with a total matching the total number of items, not batches). I guess I didn't thoroughly read the question and just assumed it was similar to what I was looking for since all the main keywords matched :)

Answer (score 22):

I know it has been quite some time, but I was looking for the same answer and here is the solution. Instead of wrapping your iterable with tqdm like this

```
for i in tqdm(my_iterable):
    do_something()
```

use a "with" close instead, as:

```
with tqdm(total=len_of_my_iterable) as progress_bar:
    for i in tqdm(my_iterable):
        do_something()
        progress_bar.update(1) # update progress
```

For your batches, you can either set the total to be the number of batches, and update to be 1 (as above). Or, you can set the total to be the actual total number of items, and the update to be the size of the current processed batch.

Comment: Just noting that if you don't have special update needs, you can simply add the total to the tqdm constructor, that is, use: `for i in tqdm(my_iterable, total=my_total)`